# Prove that if $ \phi:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{\tilde{n}} $ is a diffeomorphism, then $n= \tilde{n} $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Assume $ \mathbb{R}^{n}\supseteq\mathcal{U}\overset{\phi}{\longrightarrow}\widetilde{\mathcal{U}}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{\tilde{n}} $ is $C^1$ diffeomorphism.

How can I prove that $n=\tilde{n}$?

**My thoughts:**

I have proved the following 2 theorems:

**1.**If $ \mathbb{R}^{n}\supseteq\mathcal{U}_{p}\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}^{m} $ is a $C^r$ function such that the rank of $[f'|_p]=m $ (where $m\leq n $) then in some local coordinates at $p$ the function is $f(x_1,...,x_n)=f(p)+(x_1,...,x_m)$.

**2.**If $\mathbb{R}^{n}\supseteq\mathcal{U}_{p}\overset{f}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{R}^{m}$ where now $m\geq n$ and the rank of $[f'|_p] = n $ then in some local coordinates at $f(p)\in \mathbb{R}^m$ the function is: $f(x)=(x_1-f_1(p),...,x_n-f_n(p),0,...,0).$

So maybe I can assume for contradiction that $n\neq \tilde{n}$.
If $(n<\tilde{n}) $we'll get that $f(x)=f(p)+(x_1,...,x_m)$ which dosent seem to be injective.

If $(n>\tilde{n})$ then... (Not sure hot to continue).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In fact, it even works for homeomorphism (Brauwer's invariance of the domain).  So I guess the question is: "can we make a shorter proof by assuming diffeomorphism?"

Comment: Are you allowed to use that diffeomorphisms induce isomorphisms of the tangent spaces? if so, you can reduce the problem to linear algebra.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz I am not familier with it actually. Is it possible to prove in the way I described?